# Dotnet publish command seemingly ignores the framework argument

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, .net-core, .net-4.0

I am attempting to build and publish a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project. The build works fine, but attempting to publish gives me the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.201\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4466,5): error : MSB4803: The task "FormatUrl" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild. Please use the .NET Framework version of MSBuild. See https://aka.ms/msbuild/MSB4803 for further details. [C:\Users\ethanseal\Documents\compute-hybridrp\src\EV2Linter\EV2Linter.csproj]
Start-WindowsBuild : Encountered an error during dotnet publish C:\Users\ethanseal\Documents\xxxxxxx\Linter.sln -o
C:\Users\ethanseal\Documents\xxxxxxx\Linter --no-build
At C:\Users\ethanseal\Documents\xxxxxxx\build\build-win.ps1:63 char:1
+ Start-WindowsBuild
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Start-WindowsBuild
```

Here's the command I used:

`& dotnet publish $solution -o $outPath -f net472 --no-build`

You can see that I included an argument to specify the .NET Framework 4.7.2 framework. So why is it defaulting to .NET Core 6.0? Additionally, the project has a target framework of 4.7.2.

Comment: Where do you see Net6.0 in your error message?

Comment: @mklement0 
Running ```& dotnet -f net472 -o $outPath --no-build publish $solution  
``` just says that it can't find the command.

Running ```& dotnet publish -o $outPath -f net472 --no-build  $solution``` gives me the same error as before.

Comment: @PMF I think I messed up the formatting, but it is visible now in the first line of the error message.

Comment: @EthanSeal - yeah, sorry - the help fooled me. The options, because they are specific to the `publish` command, must go _after_ it, and where they are relative to the solution argument seemingly doesn't matter.

Comment: While the .NET Core-based SDK is capable of targeting .NET Framework in principle, it looks like your `.csproj` file contains an MSBuild task, [`FormatUrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/formaturl-task?view=vs-2022), that only the .NET Framework version of MSBuild supports. (I'm unclear on how MSBuild relates to the .NET Core SDK)

Comment: @mklement0 Yeah, it certainly seems like I'm using that task, but I can't find any reference to it in my code. I opened up my entire directory in VSCode and searched for 'formaturl', but no results came up. I am completely befuddled.